# Nested grid inside flexbox not using up full space

Tags: flexbox, css-grid

I nested a grid inside a flexbox, the grid will not use up all the space available, if I move the grid out side of flex box, it will use all space, what I'm missing here? Thanks

[jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/9tvk2wqb/1/)

```
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="grid-item">1</div>
                <div class="grid-item">2</div>
                <div class="grid-item">3</div>
                <div class="grid-item">4</div>
                <div class="grid-item">5</div>
                <div class="grid-item">6</div>
                <div class="grid-item">7</div>
                <div class="grid-item">8</div>
                <div class="grid-item">9</div>
            </div>
        </div>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: You have two elements with the `grid-container` class

Comment: That's it! Thanks